# I want this text to be aligned with the center of this special character HTML

Tags: html, css, vue.js

My navbar looks like this so far:

[image: Navbar]

But the "TMC" and the open button looks so off when its like that. I'm trying to put the TMC text in the center off the button but when i use margin-top or anything in the header it just doesn't change anything.

Here is the code:

```css
#header{
  display: inline;

}
.openbtn {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 0px 7px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.navbar{
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  height: 56px;

}
```

- "Header" is the tmc text.
- "openbtn" is the button which I want the TMC text aligned in the center of.
- "navbar" is the navbar itself.

Comment: Hey, without looking at your HTML code, it is hard to say anything. Please share it.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use flexbox for navbar, so I will explain how you can do it using flexbox:

```css
/* Removes padding and margin from the page */
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.navbar a {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.navbar svg {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  fill: white;  /* Changes the svg icon color to white */
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024"><path fill="currentColor" d="M160 448a32 32 0 0 1-32-32V160.064a32 32 0 0 1 32-32h256a32 32 0 0 1 32 32V416a32 32 0 0 1-32 32H160zm448 0a32 32 0 0 1-32-32V160.064a32 32 0 0 1 32-32h255.936a32 32 0 0 1 32 32V416a32 32 0 0 1-32 32H608zM160 896a32 32 0 0 1-32-32V608a32 32 0 0 1 32-32h256a32 32 0 0 1 32 32v256a32 32 0 0 1-32 32H160zm448 0a32 32 0 0 1-32-32V608a32 32 0 0 1 32-32h255.936a32 32 0 0 1 32 32v256a32 32 0 0 1-32 32H608z"/></svg>
  </a>
  <a href="#"><span>TMC</span></a>
</div>
```

I would suggest making your icon and text of same size.
As I have make my font-size 20px and width, height of svg(icon) 20px.

If you want to have icon of different size and text of different size you can make this change:

```css
/* Removes padding and margin from the page */
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.navbar a {
  display: flex;  /* Turns your hyperlinks into a flex item */
  font-size: 20px;
  align-items: center;  /* Aligns flex items to center */
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.navbar svg {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  fill: white;  /* Changes the svg icon color to white */
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
    <a href="#" class="icon">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024"><path fill="currentColor" d="M160 448a32 32 0 0 1-32-32V160.064a32 32 0 0 1 32-32h256a32 32 0 0 1 32 32V416a32 32 0 0 1-32 32H160zm448 0a32 32 0 0 1-32-32V160.064a32 32 0 0 1 32-32h255.936a32 32 0 0 1 32 32V416a32 32 0 0 1-32 32H608zM160 896a32 32 0 0 1-32-32V608a32 32 0 0 1 32-32h256a32 32 0 0 1 32 32v256a32 32 0 0 1-32 32H160zm448 0a32 32 0 0 1-32-32V608a32 32 0 0 1 32-32h255.936a32 32 0 0 1 32 32v256a32 32 0 0 1-32 32H608z"/></svg>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="text">TMC</a>
</div>
```